# Netbeans doesn't show error messages when it should

Tags: c++, netbeans

I've been re-learning c++. I haven't coded in c++ for quite a few years, although I really like the language, so I decided that I would re-learn it. When I first learned c++ I used dev c++ as ide. Nowadays it is seriously deprecated and I decided to use netbeans since it's the one I use for java and I'm quite accustomed to work with it.

I've set everything up in the ide, downloaded the plugin and installed the compiler and stuff. I'm having, though, a very frustrating time with the warnings of netbeans. The code itself compiles and runs fine, but netbeans doesn't seem to work very well. For example, if I create a new source file and before any compiling I write the usual `using namespace std;` there's a red wavy underline under `std` where netbeans gives the following error message "unable to resolve identifier std". If I then compile the code it disappears and everything is fine so it's not a serious problem , although it's quite an annoying behaviour.

Another, not so simple, error is if I declare a variable say `int x;`. I then use the variable `x` throughout the code, everything's fine. But if by some reason I delete the declaration statement (sometimes it happens), the rest of the code, which should by full of error messages, appears has everything's fine, no wavy red underlining...

It appears to me that netbeans only notices the errors after I compile the code... Does someone know how to fix this behaviour?

Comment: To clarify your second question, you don't remove the actual declaration, only the initialization?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If i remove the declaration 'int x'. Sorry, I should have said declaration not only the initialization. I'll quickly edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal (there is nothing wrong with Netbeans).

When editing java code, the IDE parses the code as you type and corrects immediately (or, with a relatively short delay).

When editing C++, the language is a lot more complex than Java, and while the IDE finds some errors (and underlines them), a lot of them are in code that is too complex to be parsed instantly (C++ compilation is difficult to do, and even more so, to do fast). As such, Netbeans relies on you compiling the code to update error information.

Comment: oh I see. Thank you for your response. Is this standard behaviour for all free ides for windows?